# composing canvas with Images works on Android but fails silently on IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, canvas

I have the following code which fails on IOS but works on Android `(using ionic/cordova)`. What am I missing (maybe I am being lucky with Android!) ? On Androids I get a seamless vertical stacking of image(s), whereas on IOS I get a blank look. It fails on IOS whether I am stacking one `SVG` or many.

The `SVG` elements by themselves show up fine on the page, and in `debugger` I can see their complete markup.

```
function _appendImgToCanvas(canvas, image, first_image) {
    // image contents are -- {id, h, w}
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img_type = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8";
    try {
        var img_el = document.getElementById(image.id).getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
        var img_src = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(img_el); // thx Kaiido
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = img_type + "," + img_src;
        var h = image.h, w = image.w; // is in CSS pixels
        var old_h = canvas.height, old_w = canvas.width;
        var old_image;
        if (first_image) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, old_w, old_h);
            old_h = old_w = 0; // it's a new beginning
        } else {
            old_image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // Android appears to wipe out image on resizing
        }
        // update canvas dims, and update its CSS style too
        canvas.setAttribute("height", old_h + h);
        canvas.setAttribute("width", Math.max(w, old_w));
        canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
        canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
        // retrieve any old image into the resized canvas
        if (old_image) {
            var x = new Image();
            x.src = old_image;
            ctx.drawImage(x,0,0);
        }
        // add the given image
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, old_h);
        $log.debug("IMG#" + image.id, w,"x",h, "appended at h=", old_h, "new dim=", canvas.width, "x", canvas.height);
    } catch(e){$log.error("IMG#" + image.id, "ERROR in appending", e);
            }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. on a hunch I added `timeout` of 100ms between drawing old image and new addition, and it seems to do the trick!!! As I have only at most 2-4 images to stitch it's OK for me. Timeouts of lesser amounts were not that reliable. Now I wonder why.

Comment: You have to wait for your image has loaded. Also, use  encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(yourSVGElement))` method instead of `outerHTML`/`innerHTML`, you will avoid encoding issues and this `if/else //probably ios..`

Comment: Thanks for the hint for `XMLSerializer`. But how does one wait for `drawImage` to complete? It returns `void`. Tried waiting for `element.on 'load'` but that did not fire

Comment: OK, got it, wait for `img.onload`. It still does not fire reliably on IOS but works fine on Android :-(

Comment: silly me, I had a typo `img.onload = onloadfunc()`. Fixed that, works fine on IOS too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for your images has loaded, add the drawing operations into their `onload` handler.

Also, for converting your svg element to a dataURL, use `encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(yourSVGElement))` method instead of `outerHTML`/`innerHTML`, you will avoid encoding issues and this `if/else //probably ios..`